# In Kotlin, how can I iterate a TreeMap in reversed order?

Tags: dictionary, kotlin, tree, reverse

I have a `TreeMap` and want to iterate it in reversed order. What would be an idiomatic way to do this?

```
 val tree = TreeMap(mapOf(1 to "one", 2 to "two", 3 to "three"))
 tree.forEach { println(it.key) }
```

Expected Output would be `3, 2, 1`

NOTE: this is a self-answered question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: why is this being downvoted?

Comment: I think you should add a warning "NOTE: this is a self-answered question". Otherwise the question may seem too low-effort. I got caught by that several times...

Comment: Also, even if people notice, they might not know that this is a positive thing to do here, so for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Well they should read the manual. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with this implementation of `forEachReversed`:

```
inline fun <K, V> TreeMap<K, V>.forEachReversed(action: (Map.Entry<K, V>) -> Unit) {
    descendingMap().forEach(action)
}
```

The differences from your solution are the following:

- the `K` type parameter doesn't have to be `Comparable`, which was previously required by the `reverseOrder` call
- [`descendingMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#descendingMap--) returns a view of the original `Map` instead of copying it
- the function is marked `inline` like most similar ones from the standard library

Answer (score 0):

You use reversed() method for this. Here is an Example :

```
fun sortPeople(names: Array<String>, heights: IntArray): Array<String> {
    val treeMap: TreeMap<Int, String> = TreeMap()
    names.forEachIndexed { index, s -> treeMap[heights[index]] = s }
    return treeMap.values.reversed().toTypedArray()
}
```

Or you can declare it when it initializes

```
fun sortPeople(names: Array<String>, heights: IntArray): Array<String> {
    val treeMap: TreeMap<Int, String> = TreeMap(Collections.reverseOrder())
    names.forEachIndexed { index, s -> treeMap[heights[index]] = s }
    return treeMap.values.toTypedArray()
}
```